# Cache (EHCache) fallback mechanism

Tags: java, caching, memcached, ehcache, cache-control

I have an application which has 2 service method exposed for 3rd party access that is search and book order.
When 3rd party user send search request, my application will perform search operation & will store all result bean objects in Cache (EHCache) against an unique search id.
When 3rd party user will send book order request then all result bean object are taken from cache & getting used in book order flow. Here, caching all result data object is mandatory.

Lets assume that 3rd party user had done search and now they have send book order request. But between 2 user call my cache app got crashed due to some problem or some problem in cache after search data stored in cache. Now when 3rd party user will send book order request to my application, as the required data is not in cache, book order will not be processed.

How to handle cache fallback mechanism for above scenario.

Could any one please advise any read-up on this.

Comment: What is the management?

Comment: @nikpon  cache fall back mechanism.

Comment: Do you know what is it?

Comment: EHCache is a tool which helps in caching data and objects in RAM to reduce the no. of hits to database or an external data source. It's used for boosting performance, offloading your database, and simplifying scalability.

Comment: What is a cache fallback mechanism?

Comment: cache fallback mechanism = If cache got failed in middle of any transaction then is there any mechanism in EHCache OR any other tool OR other mechanism to get cached data back to proceed further without interruption.

Comment: what a transaction cause it fail?

Comment: that may be network failed or cache server issue..

Comment: Is it good idea to store objects in cache & for fallback mechanism store same objects using other tool/technology. so that when cache data objects are not available then get data object from other tool/technology..

Comment: Java bean object can be stored in MongoDB as MongoDB Object/document using [Moprphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) or [jongo](http://jongo.org/) or object can also be convert into json string using the [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. Using these tools, java objects can be retrieved from MongoDB. Is there any other better solution for above mentioned question.